# Make server inaccessible to anything but REST requests

Tags: rest, security, server

Is there a way to make a machine that is connected to the internet unreachable by any means except REST requests? For background as to my quetion:

I have a really nice REST server/client project, with encrypted communication, in which the weak spot in the encryption technique is the code. Without seeing the code it is impossible to break the encryption, but if you see the code it is probably possible to figure out how to decrypt intercepted communication.

Due to this, I would like the server code at least to be as well protected as possible. Is there a way to make a machine that is connected to the internet unreachable by any means except REST requests to stop any hope of an attacker gaining access to the code or data that the server is serving up? I'm open to the idea of a bare metal solution if that would make for the safest system, the server's only job really will be just to server information requested via REST requests and nothing else.

(I'm aware this will still leave the client code as a weak spot, but I'm taking this one step at a time. Protecting the client code is presumably going to be a much bigger problem and probably impossible as I intend to eventually distribute the client executables).

Comment: API Gateway might be helpful.

Comment: Cheers, I'm checking out some info on it. I'll let you know if that helped